# Any concerns with mounting a JFS2 filesystem under an NFS mount?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, aix

We have many instances where we mount JFS2 filesystems underneath other JFS2 filesystems (eg. /fs1, /fs1/fs2, etc...) but we've never done it with NFS.

Is there anything to be aware of when doing this? It appears to work just fine, I'm just worried about any "gotchas" while doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Greater risk of the jfs2 fs not mounting or being later hidden if the nfs fs doesn't mount first

Answer (score 0):

NFS is dependent on networks availability. For a long time, I have not seen systems admin team and network admin team reporting to the same manager. Hence the communications between the two groups is usually less than ideal. I believe you are understanding where I am coming at. If network guys schedule a maintenance, supposedly transparent to everyone and don't notify you, so that you gracefully unmount these NFS mounts in an orderly fashion, you will end up wit stale NFS mounts, which, in the worst of the circumstances, may force you to reboot the server. And if these are production servers, you will have proverbial black eye in front of all business units.

In my opinion, it is never a good practice to mount filesystems in a nested way, regardless they are disk based filesystems or network based, but NFS over NFS or anything over NFS is a very bad idea.

Comment: NFS over NFS is fine if both exported dir are on same serveur. Before doing any mount, just think: how will my syste